# Trying to dynamically create a div and append it to body element but not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html, append

I browsed a few questions here regarding dynamically injecting a `div` to the `body` element. It seems pretty simple, but for some reason, this is not working:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "uniqueID";
document.body.appendChild( div );
```

The specific error is returned in Google Chrome's developer console: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null.**

Answer (score 5):

Are you running this script after the DOM has been loaded? For example,

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code
};
```

Comment: DUHH!!! Oh god. Thanks! I didn't think about that. And I'm using jQuery anyway so I went with `$(document).ready(function(){ });` Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
const myDiv = document.getelementByID(`DivId`)
myDiv.setAtribute(`Id`,`UniqueId`)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This doesn't answer the original question of *why* the error was occurring.  See the other answer for that.  While the OP didn't accept the answer, they commented on it and confirmed that was the problem in this case. Your answer also doesn't even seem to demonstrate how to *dynamically create a div* as the question was referring to.

Comment: The question doesn't ask why, it just says it isn't working.  Giving working code is a legitimate attempt to answer the question.  If a  code-only answer isn't high quality, it should be down-voted rather than flagged.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.